# Callback called more than once while running npm install

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having some trouble to deploy my Node.JS application to AWS using ElasticBeanStalk.

As soon as the deploy starts, while running the `npm install` script (default by AWS), I get the following weird error:

```
material-ui@0.15.4 node_modules/material-ui
  ├── simple-assign@0.1.0
  ├── react-addons-create-fragment@15.3.2
  ├── react-addons-transition-group@15.3.2
  ├── keycode@2.1.7
  ├── warning@3.0.0 (loose-envify@1.2.0)
  ├── inline-style-prefixer@2.0.4 (hyphenate-style-name@1.0.1, bowser@1.4.6)
  ├── lodash@4.16.2
  ├── react-event-listener@0.2.1 (fbjs@0.8.5)
  └── recompose@0.20.2 (symbol-observable@0.2.4, change-emitter@0.1.2, hoist-non-react-statics@1.2.0, fbjs@0.8.5)
  npm ERR! Linux 4.1.17-22.30.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.3.0-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "install"
  npm ERR! node v4.3.0
  npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12

  npm ERR! Callback called more than once.
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
  npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!     /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log
```

Can anyone help me debug this problem? I've already spent too many hours trying to understand what is happening, but got no results so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently some AWS regions do have connection problems with npm (as related in this [issue](https://github.com/npm/registry/issues/10)) and I solved it by forcing npm to download modules via `http` instead of `https`. 
To do that I added a `.npmrc` file to the root directory of my project with the following content: 
`registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Thanks **[@Jason Livesay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281920/jason-livesay)** for the tips and **[@danilojun](https://github.com/danilojun)** for helping me find the best solution!

Comment: I ran into this problem today as well, deploying in region eu-west. Found that simply retrying works most of the time, so it's really intermittent, but using http seems to give a bit more deterministic results.

Answer (score 6):

Updating `npm` solved it for me

```
npm i -g npm
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste the full log please. Verify that theVMs have adequate network and other resources (free/cheap AWS stuff gets throttled).  Upgrade to latest Node/npm.  See numerous comments on github npm repo issues such as https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9418#issuecomment-170244027 and others when you search that error in github isshes.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I derived for a project I was working on was to check in the node_modules folder to source and then disable the automatic npm install inherit to EB. This can help with fragile node apps with strict dependencies.

You would need to add the following script to the .ebextensions:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: users
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      #==============================================================================
      # Copyright 2013 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
      #
      # Licensed under the Amazon Software License (the "License"). You may not use
      # this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the License is
      # located at
      #
      #       http://aws.amazon.com/asl/
      #
      # or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed on
      # an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, express or
      # implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions
      # and limitations under the License.
      #==============================================================================

      #set -xe
      #DO NOT RUN NPM...project contains node_modules
      #/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
```